# EPS figure fonts don't show correctly

Tags: python, fonts

I was trying to plot a figure to EPS format using PyPlot. But the fonts in the EPS figure don't show correctly -- they look squeezed all together. (Unfortunately I couldn't show the image)

The fonts show correctly in all other formats, just not in EPS, but some publications require figures in EPS format.

I've tried all I could, including changing all backends, changing fonts, changing fonttype. None of them worked. In the mean time, I asked colleagues and none of them had the problem, or had to tweak any default settings.

Here's how I make a plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,100,100))
plt.title('This is the title')
plt.xlable('This is the X label')
plt.savefig('test.eps',format='eps')
```

And when I tried to open with MacOSX Preview, it prompts: "Converting the PostScript file “test.eps” produced the following warnings:
· b'Verdana' not found, using Courier."

Changing the sequence of the font.serif parameter or deleting some fonts in the  matplotlibrc file didn'e help either. How to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK. Since no one answered my question I went on and did a lot of research on this. 
I still couldn't find a solution but I found a work-around.

If I set text.usetex=1 in the matplotlibrc file the fonts will then show up correctly. The downside is that there will be lots of tex cache files generated and it seems really slow. But at least the fonts are now readable.